# Detecting the data type of a user-entered input

Tags: jquery

How can I detect the data type, load the data type into a variable, and then run appropriate 'if' statements based on the data type?

This seems to think everything's a string:

```
$("#input1").change(function(){
    var keyboard_input = $(this).val();
    alert("That was a " + jQuery.type(keyboard_input));
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BJSp8/3/)

Comment: What would you expect an input to receive, if not a string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything the user enters into the input field **is** a string - a sequence of characters entered from keyboard.

If you want to get eg. integers and booleans, you will have to parse this string.

---

To get a boolean, you can check if the string equals to `'true'` or `'false'`.
 
To get numeric values, you will have to use some regular expression.

Here's an **[example JsFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BJSp8/4/)** to give you a starting point.